# TypeScript Error in React component on useState declaration and passing props to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I started using TypeScript with React and currently building a sample App for practice, just fetching data from public API and implementing CRUD alongside with Material UI but I'm facing errors in two components, so I would much appreciate your help.

The first error is on passing function via props to a child component, and the second one is on declaring useState using a custom Interface I created for my data type.

The first component is PostTable.tsx

```
const PostsTable: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState<Array<IPost>>([]);
  const [selectedPost, setSelectedPost] = useState<IPost | null>(null);
  const [dialogOpen, setDialogOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const fetchPosts = () => {
    PostService.getAllPosts()
      .then((response: any) => {
        setPosts(response.data);
      })
      .catch((e: Error) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPosts();
  }, [posts]);

  const editPost = (post: IPost) => (event: any) => {
    setSelectedPost(post);
    setDialogOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setDialogOpen(false);
  };

  const deletePost =
    (id: number): any =>
    (event: Event) => {
      event.stopPropagation();
      PostService.deletePost(id)
        .then((response: any) => {
          setPosts(response.data);
          console.log(posts);
        })
        .catch((e: Error) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    };

  return (
    <Container fixed>
      {!posts || posts.length < 1 ? (
        <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <CircularProgress color="primary" size={100} />
        </div>
      ) : (
        <TableContainer component={Paper}>
          <Table sx={{ minWidth: 650 }} aria-label="simple table">
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell align="left">User Id</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="left">Post Id</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="left">Title</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="left">Actions</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
              {posts.map((post: IPost) => (
                <TableRow
                  key={post.id}
                  sx={{ '&:last-child td, &:last-child th': { border: 0 } }}
                >
                  <TableCell>{post.userId}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="left">{post.id}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="left">{post.title}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="left">
                    <Tooltip title="Delete">
                      <IconButton onClick={editPost(post)}>
                        <EditIcon />
                      </IconButton>
                    </Tooltip>
                    <Tooltip title="Edit">
                      <IconButton onClick={deletePost(post.id)}>
                        <DeleteIcon />
                      </IconButton>
                    </Tooltip>
                  </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              ))}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
      )}
      {
        <EditPostDialog
          open={dialogOpen}
          handleClose={handleClose}
          /**Error is on this line**/
          selectedPost={selectedPost}
        />
      }
    </Container>
  );
};
```

And also second, the child EditPostDialog.ts

```
const EditPostDialog: React.FunctionComponent<IEditPostDialog> = (
  props: IEditPostDialog
) => {
  const { open, handleClose, selectedPost } = props;
  /**Error on this line**/
  const [post, setPost] = useState<IPost>({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const newPost = {
      id: selectedPost.id,
      userId: selectedPost.userId,
      title: selectedPost.title,
      body: selectedPost.body,
    };
    setPost(newPost);
  }, [selectedPost]);

  const handleChange = (event: any) => {
    setPost({ ...post, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    PostService.updatePost(post.id, post);
    handleClose();
  };

  return (
    <Dialog onClose={handleClose} open={open}>
      <DialogTitle id="simple-dialog-title">Post info</DialogTitle>
      <DialogContent classes={{ root: 'dialog-content' }}>
        <TextField
          id="id"
          label="Post Id"
          name="id"
          variant="outlined"
          value={post.id}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <TextField
          id="userId"
          label="User Id"
          name="userId"
          variant="outlined"
          value={post.userId}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <TextField
          id="title"
          label="Title"
          name="title"
          variant="outlined"
          value={post.title}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <TextField
          id="body"
          label="Body"
          name="body"
          variant="outlined"
          value={post.body}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </DialogContent>
      <DialogActions>
        <Button onClick={handleClose}>Close</Button>
        <Button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</Button>
      </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
  );
};
```

You probably need IPost interface, so there it is:

```
export default interface IPost {
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  body: string;
}
```

And at the end IEditPost interface:

```
export default interface IEditPostDialog {
  open: boolean;
  handleClose: () => void;
  selectedPost: IPost;
}
```

Thank you all in the advance!

Comment: Can your provide the `IEditPostDialog`? The first error is basically that you initialize the state of type `IPost` with an empty object. But the interface expects all of your properties to be present. You can omit that by appending a `?` after the name of the property.

Comment: Sorry, totally forgot about the second Interface. I edited my question, you can see it now.

Answer (score 0):

The second error is basically that you initialize the state of type `IPost` with an empty object. But the interface expects all of your properties to be present. You can omit that by appending a `?` after the name of the property.

You can simplify your child component to solve this:

```js
const [post, setPost] = useState<IPost>(selectedPost);

  useEffect(() => {
    setPost(selectedPost);
  }, [selectedPost]);
```

In case of your other problem:
First of all, you do not need to specify `null` explicitly:

```js
// Your code: const [selectedPost, setSelectedPost] = useState<IPost | null>(null);
const [selectedPost, setSelectedPost] = useState<IPost>(null); // should work perfectly fine
```

We need to see the interface `IEditPostDialog` to see whats the problem with passing the value `selectedPost` to the unterlying component.

Comment: Sorry, totally forgot about the second Interface. I edited my question, you can see it now.

Comment: Thanks, in that case just change `<IPost | null>` to `<IPost>` or change the expected type in the interface `IEditPostDialog`. Thats because `<IPost | null> !== <IPost>`

Comment: That was my first thought, but when I try this, linter throws me an error at that null, saying Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type IPost

Comment: Thats why I said "or change the expected type in the interface". You need to have the same type signatures.